# adding to an existing Object prototype in typescript

Tags: typescript, wallaby.js

I'm using the fantastic Wallaby testing solution to run realtime tests but it -- by default -- intercepts **stdout** and **stderr** (for good reasons). In the cases where I *do not* want this to happen I can override the behavior by tucking a variable into the `console` command like so:

```
console._restored = true;
```

this will be picked up by the Wallaby test runner and temporarily send the event streams back to their normal destinations. This solution works just fine but Typescript isn't happy:
[image: ts error message]

I am trying to find some way in which to add to the *prototype* definition of the "Console" interface.

In my first crude attempt, I just looked up the NodeJS definition of **Console** and added to my test helper file with the `_restored` property added:

[image]

As with most cases of desperation it ended in tears. Apparently the already defined global definition is still used.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial attempt was actually close to being right. You can redefine the interface `Console` as:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line
interface Console {
    _restored: boolean;
    Console: typeof NodeJS.Console;
    assert(value: any, message?: string, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    dir(obj: any, options?: {showHidden?: boolean, depth?: number, colors?: boolean}): void;
    error(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    info(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    time(label: string): void;
    timeEnd(label: string): void;
    trace(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
    warn(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void;
}
```

But then you must also **declare** `console` as your newly defined interface:

```
declare var console: Console;
```

With this defined in my test helper file, I can now add the following function without error:

```
export function restoreStdoutAndStderr() {
  console._restored = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the **Console** interface with the property you want to add works in the playground:

```js
interface Console {
    _restored: boolean;
}

console._restored = true;
```

You can see it working [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Console%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_restored%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole._restored%20%3D%20true%3B).

However this does not seem to work when you use modules. In that case you have to define the **Console** interface in a **.d.ts** file.

```
interface Console {
    _restored: boolean;
}
```

anywhereelse.ts:

```js
import * as something from './something';


console._restored = true;
```

Comment: Strange. I'm sure that I tried that but let me try again. Also, not sure my version is that different ... I include what you suggest but also add in the standard definition.

Comment: Yes I believe the reason you are not running into the error is that you are not using the @types/node definition first ... I DO want this for all the rest of my code, it's only in a few testing situation where I need to extend the interface.

Comment: @ken please try to make the interface definition in a .d.ts file. :)

Comment: not sure how practical that is ... it's shame there's no online playground that allows for adding in npm modules like **@types/node**; it is very easily reproducible in local environment right? You can also find the standard .d.ts at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v6/index.d.ts

Comment: if you want that you can use plnkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah but this is all browser based, not node and commonjs. Or is there a way to do that?

Comment: you can run commonjs in the browser too. :) and, no you can't really get nodejs in browser.